# Why isn't my register (R0) pointing to the new address in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

```
    
    ldr R0, =str1       @ str1 = "-400"
    bl putstring        @ putstring displays the number

    ldr R0, =newline    @ Load R0 with address of newline (newline: .byte 10)
    bl  putch           @ Function call to ext. func. call putch (putch outputs a character)
```

I want the second portion of the code to output a newline. However, R0 isn't pointing to the address of newline, despite the instruction.

```
$r0  : 0x0002064c  →  "-400"
$r1  : 0x0002064c  →  "-400"

@ After 2nd ldr instruction
$r0  : 0x0002064f  →  0x30340030 ("0"?)
$r1  : 0x0002064c  →  "-400"
```

Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't R0 be pointing to a newline address, so that it may be outputted using putch? Why is it pointing to a '0' from the "-400"?

The value of R0 SHOULD be:

```
$r0  : 0x0002064f  →  <newline+0> lsrs r0,  r0,  #8
```

after the 2nd ldr instruction.

Declarations:

```
str1:       .asciz ""

newline:        .byte  10
```

Comment: Show more code, please.  How did you define the labels `str1` and `newline`, and what data did you assemble at those locations? But more importantly, are you sure `putch` is actually expecting an address - it might be expecting the character itself in the register.  In which case you'd just want to `mov R0, #'\n'`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I commented the declaration for ```newline``` in my question. ```putch``` is expecting R0 to point to a character byte. Which should be ```newline .byte 10```.

Comment: Added declarations. @NateEldredge

Comment: I thought you said `str1` contained the string `"-400"`, but you initialize it to an empty string (i.e. just a null byte).  Did your code try to store the string `"-400"` there at runtime?  There was only one byte reserved at address `str1`, so if you try to store 5 bytes there, it's going to overwrite whatever comes next in memory, which perhaps is the `10` byte at `newline`.  (Their addresses aren't consecutive in your debug output, so maybe there is something else in between that you didn't show us; it's toast too.)

Comment: @NateEldredge So are old values bleeding over to my new load instructions? I stored the string later after the declaration. I assumed I was declaring an empty string. I've redeclared my ```str1``` with three spaces and the newlines have actually been loaded into my registers. Not sure why this is the case.

Comment: Remember, assembly is not a high-level language, and strings and buffers don't magically expand when you write more stuff to them.  `.asciz ""` assembles an empty string at address `0x2064c`, which is to say it places one null byte there, and then the following memory gets used for something else.  When you store five bytes starting at address `0x2064c`, you thus overwrite the bytes at addresses `0x2064c` through `0x20650`.  That includes the byte at `0x2064f` which was your `newline`.

Comment: If you want to be able to store `"-400"`, which I assume is null terminated, you need to reserve 5 bytes.  `str1: .space 5`  If you'll use this space for other strings, you need to figure out in your source the maximum length you will ever need there.  Or use the stack for temporary strings instead.

Comment: Do you know C?  You've done the equivalent of `char str1[] = ""; strcpy(str1, "-400");`.  A classic buffer overflow.

Comment: @NateEldredge That makes sense. I haven't had experience in C, but I completely overlooked that. Would there be any downsides to declaring a string of a larger size than I would need? Just to play it safe? Doing ```.space 100``` worked fine for me.

Comment: It just wastes that memory, that's all.  Unless your machine has a very tiny amount of RAM there's no significant downside.